# Lost internet connection while installing

Tags: apt, software-installation, internet

I wanted to install keepassx and did `apt-get install keepassx` but then my I lost my internet connection whilst installing.

Is there anything to fix?

Comment: You should run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall keepassx` now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on when during the installation you lost connection. If you lost it after the download completed you (most likely) aren't going to have problems. However, just to be safe I'd recommend you to check and make sure it works as intended (If it doesn't work properly please run `sudo apt-get purge keepassx; sudo apt-get install keepassx`)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, too. It continued to install when the internet was reinstated. It took maybe two minutes to start installing again once internet was connected.